# ASP.NET MVC 5 external authentication with Twitter's new policy

Tags: ssl, twitter, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I have been trying this authentication method for the last 3 days without any success, I am totally new to the field MVC and Identity. I required to do an external authentication for my site with Facebook, Microsoft and Twitter, so I am using Identity 2.0 with MVC 5.
Facebook and Microsoft are already done, but I have trouble doing the same for twitter, because they change their authentication policy last December, so now I require an HTTPS site (which is not the problem) with a Twitter SSL certificate (I have problems with this one).
I am using IIS Express to run my website in development mode.
I already created my app on twitter's developer site, I got my API key, API Secret, Access Token and Access Secret.
I already change my Startup.Auth.cs, to uncomment app.UseTwitterAuthentication with my consumerKey (ApiKey) and consumerSecret (ApiSecret). But when I run my site and try to sign-in with Twitter I keep receiving this error: the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

See these discussion issues: 
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/security/using-ssl

Reading a little bit about this issue, I know require a Twitter SSL certificate, which I got, but cannot figure out how to use it.

Please, I am desperate and I need a solution to this problem, can anyone enlighten me on how to make this work with VS 2013 and IIS Express? I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... now I require an HTTPS site (which is not the problem) with a Twitter SSL certificate (I have problems with this one)

According to [Twitter is updating its SSL certificates for api.twitter.com](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/ssl-upgrade-for-twitterapi), the signing root is changing to `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5`.

It appears it has already changed:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect api.twitter.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10, CN = VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=Twitter, Inc./OU=Twitter Security/CN=api.twitter.com
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
 1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
...
```

Go to [Download Verisign Root Certificates](https://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots) and download *VeriSign Class 3 Primary CA - G5*. It has thumbprint `4e b6 d5 78 49 9b 1c cf 5f 58 1e ad 56 be 3d 9b 67 44 a5 e5`.

After downloading the certificate, import it into the Computer's Root Certificate Authority Store. For instuctions, see [Manage Trusted Root Certificates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx) on TechNet. Be sure to follow *Adding certificates to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store for a local computer*. You want the local computer, and you want Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.

Once you use the downloaded certificate as a trust anchor, the chain will verify. Notice the `-CAfile` option, and the `Verify return code: 0 (ok)` at the end:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect api.twitter.com:443 -CAfile VeriSign-Class\ 3-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10, CN = VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = "Twitter, Inc.", OU = Twitter Security, CN = api.twitter.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=Twitter, Inc./OU=Twitter Security/CN=api.twitter.com
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
 1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
---
...

    Start Time: 1407206791
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```